# Dynamically created layer names, problems with eval()

Tags: eval, layer, openlayers-3

I want to create some layers with names taken from database. "Trees" in database becomes a "Layer_Trees" openlayers layer.
I tried many things with **eval** function, yet with no success. Seems like its completely uncapable of defining new variables.

```
function addLayer_ImageWMS(SourceName,SourceLayerName) {

    LayerName="Layer_" + SourceLayerName;

    eval(LayerName) = new ol.layer.Image({
        title: LayerName,                
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: SourceName,
            params: {
            'LAYERS': SourceLayerName, 
            'TRANSPARENT': 'true'
            }
        })
    })  
    LayersArray.push(LayerName);

}
```

If I remove "eval()" everything is working, but layers are inaccessible from outside.
Openlayers 3. I have to adress this layers from outside of this function, because they are turned on and off through a menu.
Is there any simple way to do this?

I was planning to turn them on and off with such code:

```
SourceName = "Layer_" + $(layer).children("#SourceName").val();
IsChecked = $(layer).children(".Style_LayerList_Radiobutton").prop("checked");
eval(SourceName).setVisible(IsChecked);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `eval` for this. Simply use an object like this:

```
var layers = {};
layers['Layer_' + SourceLayerName] = new ...;
```

Later you can access the layer with:

```
layers['Layer_Trees'].setVisible(true);
```